# how to include java script when you have ajax and css?

Tags: javascript

when I run my javascript in my index.html it works properly but I wanted to seperate it as a js file
so I created aram.js and then I added my code to it
I also included this line to index:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="aram.js"></script>
```

aram.js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            $(function() {
                $('#accordion > li').hover(
                    function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        $this.stop().animate({'width':'480px'},500);
                        $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut();
                        $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideDown(500);
                        $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                    },
                    function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        $this.stop().animate({'width':'115px'},1000);
                        $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                        $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(500);
                        $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideUp(700);
                    }
                );
            });
```

I think the problem is that It can't find the css I have style.css in a css folder which is included in index.html like this line:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

Comment: Including a `<script>` tag in your JS file is a problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the script tag to include jquery above your javascript include file. These two includes should be in your html.

Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="aram.js"></script>
```

This will then load jquery first so your javascript (which uses jquery) can be executed.

Answer (score 2):

you can't write  tag inside a .js file. you should call jquery inside index.html, too.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to wrap your js in `<script>` tags if it is in a `.js` file.

Also, you cannot use html tags in your javascript file. This script tag belongs on your html file, ordered like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="aram.js"></script>
```

JS files have only js

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally you would reference both the jQuery javascript file and your own javascript file from the HTML file.  Putting an HTML script tag inside your javascript file is not going to work correctly.

If you really want to only include one script element in the HTML file, it should be possible to use this code to inject the jquery code from that file:

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>');
```

However, this technique does not have much to recommend it in this case.

Comment: Oh, I agree, although a situation might arise in which it becomes necessary to do such a thing.

Comment: I have wordpress and yes you were right I should have wrote the script in the html but in wordpress I think I should have just js files ini js folder so not even 1 script should be in html what should I do?

Comment: You'll have to get WordPress to include the script elements in its HTML output somehow.  Unfortunately I have no idea what that would be because I don't use it.